# Trying to change first array address using the pass by references technique in C++, using 2 methods

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

I am trying to assign the first array address to another array, by passing the reference of the first array to the `change_values()`, and changing it inside the function, so that all the first array's values are changed.

For achieving that, I have tried 2 different methods, the first one by using
pointers, e.g. `int* x = new int[3]`, and the second one is by using
static arrays, e.g. `int x[3]`.

Here is the first method:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void change_values(int*& nums) {
    
    int* nums2 = new int[3];
    
    nums2[0] = 1;
    nums2[1] = 2;
    nums2[2] = 3;
    
    nums = nums2;
}

void print_values(int* nums) {
    cout << nums[0] << "  " << nums[1] << "  " << nums[2];
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    
    int* x = new int(3);
    x[0] = 5;
    x[1] = 10;
    x[2] = 15;
    
    change_values(x);
    
    print_values(x);

    return 0;
}
```

The program outputs :
1  2  3

So the first address of nums was set to the first address to nums2 successfully.

And here is the second method:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void change_values(int (&nums)[3]) {
    
    int nums2[3];
    
    nums2[0] = 1;
    nums2[1] = 2;
    nums2[2] = 3;
    
    nums = nums2;
}

void print_values(int nums[]) {
    cout << nums[0] << "  " << nums[1] << "  " << nums[2];
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    
    int x[3];
    x[0] = 5;
    x[1] = 10;
    x[2] = 15;
    
    change_values(x);
    
    print_values(x);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler generates an error :

```
In function 'void change_values(int (&)[3])':
/tmp/Zmp06HOavn.cpp:12:12: error: invalid array assignment
   12 |     nums = nums2;
```

Can I know why is it giving this error, what should I change to make it succeed
using the second syntax?

Comment: In the second case you're passing an "array by reference" while in the first case you're passing a "pointer by reference"

Comment: you can use `std::array` instead.

Comment: `int* nums2 = new int(3);` allocates a single `int` with the value `3` – trying to access any index other than 0 invokes undefined behaviour. You want `int* nums2 = new int[3];`

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes you are right, I have edited it. But as a side note, sometimes you can type `int* nums2 = new int(3)`, and still be able to access *(x+1) and *(x+2) .. because they are allocated and set to 0 by coincidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I know why is it giving this error

Because in the second case you're passing an array by reference. That is, the parameter `nums` in the second case is a reference to an array of size `3` with elements of type `int` but since we can't assign a built in array to another built in array, we get the mentioned error. Note that in the second case the type of `nums` is `int [3]` which is an **array type**.

---

On the other hand, in the first case you're passing a pointer by reference. That is, in the first case the parameter `nums` is actually a reference to a pointer to a non-const `int`.

Note in this first case, the type of `nums` is `int*` which is a **pointer type**.

Comment: Mmm but isn't a pointer actually a dynamic array? I mean that int x[3], will reserve memory for 3 ints and will return the address of the first, and int* x = new int(3) will do the same ...

Comment: @XY No, a pointer is not actually an array. The type of `nums` in second case is `int [3]` while the type of `nums` in first case is `int*`. In certain cases(not always), an array decays to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Yes you are right, the assignments of one static array to another is not permitted at all, even without using references, that is also the same in the C language. But what is point of allowing the pass by reference of an array, if its value can not be changed?

Comment: @XY thats actually not too weird. You'd also get a compiler error for different custom type when it has not assignment operator

Comment: @XY Note that its not that you're not allowed to change the array but that you cannot assign it to another array. You can confirm this(in your 2nd example) by replacing `nums = nums2;` with `nums[0]=3;` and you'll see that it will work showing that we're allowed to change the array. It's just that you cannot assign that complete array to another array.

Comment: Yeah but `nums[0] = 3` actually changes the value with passing-by-reference and without,  so what is the point of letting you pass an array by reference?

Comment: @XY The point is that when you pass by reference then there is no copy involved of the object. You're making changes on the actual object.

Comment: I have found one definite necessity for that, when you declare a function this way `void f(int (&arr)[3]);` compiler only accepts arrays that have length of 3.

Comment: @XY Yes, and if you want you can also use templates like `template<std::size_t N> void f( int(&arr)[N]);` to pass array of any length(like `4`, `120` etc) by reference.